# JS countdown in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, countdown

For a website, I need a countdown to a specific date. I tried to write such a code by myself in Javascript, but I failed. So I searched for a template. I found one on Stack Overflow and it worked really good. But I have one problem. I need to format the days, hours, minutes and the seconds seperately. In the code I found, everything is written by the Javascript into one single div. So I want the Javascript to edit all 4 divs seperately (days, hrs, mins, secs). Can someone help me please?

```
<script>
    var end = new Date('07/16/2017 00:00 AM');

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    </script>
    <div id="countdown">

        <div id="days"></div>
        <div id="hrs"></div>
        <div id="mins"></div>
        <div id="secs"></div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope can help!

link run online : https://jsbin.com/sivejolapi/edit?html,output

```
<script>
    var end = new Date('07/16/2017 00:00 AM');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        document.getElementById('hrs').innerHTML = hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById('secs').innerHTML = seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
<div class="countdown">

    <div id="days"></div>
    <div id="hrs"></div>
    <div id="mins"></div>
    <div id="secs"></div>

</div>
```

`

Answer (score 3):

All you have to change is :

```
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
```

Give the *correct* div id instead of `countdown` for all and change `.innerHTML +=` to `.innerHTML =`

```html
<script>
    var end = new Date('07/16/2017 00:00 AM');

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
            document.getElementById('hrs').innerHTML = hours + 'hrs ';
            document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = minutes + 'mins ';
            document.getElementById('secs').innerHTML = seconds + 'secs';
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    </script>
    <div id="countdown">

        <div id="days"></div>
        <div id="hrs"></div>
        <div id="mins"></div>
        <div id="secs"></div>

    </div>
```